# How to do map.put(key,value) in drools? Note :I am using mvel dialect

Tags: drools, mvel

1)How to do `map.put(key,value)` in drools?

2)if one of the attribute of a fact/pojo is map, how can i put a entry to that map attribute? 
i.e `myPojo.getMapAttrValue().put(key,value)`;

Note :I am using **mvel** dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy:

```
//Assuming you have a class called 'Fact' with an attribute 
//called 'map' of type Map
rule "Sample 1"
when
    $f: Fact()
then
    $f.getMap().put("key", "value");
end
```

The right hand side of a rule is basically java, so you can write whatever java code you want in there.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the help.

One more question, How can I do in inside when block?

Comment: The when part is supposed to be a pattern against which the facts in your session will be tested. It is not a very good idea to modify them in there.